# How can I figure out why this process is terminated On Ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, logging, kernel, lstm

I tried to run a python script which trains a lstm model on a server.

Here is the server's os information.
[image: Here is the server's os information.]

However,everytime before the traning ends,the process will be terminated.

the screenshot of the terminated process
[image: the screenshot of the terminated process]

(Thanks to Barmar's advice,I update some command)
[image: information of the terminated process & memory used]

But I found that the cmd 'ps -aux' isn't consistent to the cmd 'free -mt'&'vmstat -a'.

I suspect If the kernel killed the process (because the system ran out of memory).So I try to find the kernel log.

But there's no piece of log file that I want listing under /var/log.

[image: the listed files under /var/log]

Can anyone help me find what really happened in the running of the python script?
Or tell me how to find some logs recording why this process is terminated?

Comment: I suspect it ran out of virtual memory.

Comment: Look at the huge VSZ column.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your advice! I edited my question,a new confusing problem merged .

Comment: [unix.se] would be a better place to post this.